# How to extract adjacant elements in the dom by inner html

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I would like to extract adjacent DOM elements by searching for innerHtml text. The elements are not children of a wrapping parent. An example will make it easier to understand:

```
<p>1.</p>
<h1>This is the first paragraph..</h1>
<button>click</button>

<p>2.</p>
<h3>And this is the second...</h3>
<img src="" alt=""/>

<p>3.</p>
<h5>this is the last paragraph</h5>
```

I would like to find the first element by looking for the inner text of "1." and then extract all its siblings until I reach the first element with the inner text of "2."

And then do it with 2 and 3 and so on. All the elements are siblings. The extract could be moving the elements into an array as plain text for example.

Is it possible to achieve?
Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Yes. So what exactly you have a problem with? You described algorithm... Just write the code... Some clarification may improve the question (or maybe code you've tried and stuck at)

Comment: You could give the adjacent elements a meaningful class or ID (id="1") which would make it easier.

Comment: If I target the element with the text of "1." I know how to add a class to it for example, but how can I target all its adjacent elements until I reach the element with "2." ?
Thanks

Comment: afishintaiwan How can I give them a class, namely how can I target them knowing that they are after the element with "1." and before the element with "2." ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this could be achieved via the use of the `.nextSibling` field on DOM nodes.

This would allow you to access the next sibling node to the current node being processed (ie the first `p` element in your document). You could use this to iterate through all valid siblings, searching for any with `innerText` matching your the criteria and adding those to a list of extracted nodes like so:

```js
var extracted = [];

/*
Get starting node for search. In this case we'll start
with the first p element
*/
var p = document.querySelector('p');

/*
Iterate through each sibiling of p
*/
do {
  
  /*
  If this sibling node has innerText that matches the
  number pattern required, add this node to the list of
  extracted nodes
  */
  if(p.innerText && p.innerText.match(/\d+./gi)) {
    extracted.push(p.innerText);
  }
  
  /*
  Move to next sibling
  */
  p = p.nextSibling;
}
while(p) /* Iterate while sibing is valid */

console.log('Extracted plain text for nodes with number string for innerText:', extracted);
```

```html
<p>1.</p>
<h1>This is the first paragraph..</h1>
<button>click</button>

<p>2.</p>
<h3>And this is the second...</h3>
<img src="" alt="" />

<p>3.</p>
<h5>this is the last paragraph</h5>
```

Comment: are you sure OP wants to push the `p` in array ?

Comment: @RajnishCoder thanks for spotting that - just noticed the OP asked for an array of strings. Have updated answer :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot mate that was really helpful

Answer (score 2):

You can check the `nextElementSibling` with `while` like the following way:

```js
var arrP = ['1.','2.','3.'];
var allP =  document.querySelectorAll('p');
allP.forEach(function(p){
  if(arrP.includes(p.textContent)){
    var siblings = [];
    elem = p.nextElementSibling;
    while(elem) {
      if (elem.nodeName == 'P' || elem.nodeName == 'SCRIPT') break;
      siblings.push(elem);
      elem = elem.nextElementSibling;
    }
    console.log(siblings);
  }
});
```

```html
<p>1.</p>
<h1>This is the first paragraph..</h1>
<button>click</button>

<p>2.</p>
<h3>And this is the second...</h3>
<img src="" alt=""/>

<p>3.</p>
<h5>this is the last but one paragraph</h5>

<p>Not.</p>
<h5>this is the last paragraph</h5>
```

Comment: You are checking all `p` tags but OP specified only those which contains `1.` and `2.` so on.

Comment: @RajnishCoder, I am not sure about the text inside as all the next element until next p element are inside separate arrays......

Comment: yes it is, but a page can contains any amount of `<p>` tags and your query will get all the next sibling elements of all the `p` tags in whole DOM, I don't think your answer is bug free :D

Comment: @RajnishCoder, I am not quite sure about the point....Though I have update the answer by maintaining an array of text of p elements to loop through.....Hope this will work now as your requirements......thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer